# layer.update not a function?

Tags: javascript, typeerror

I'm new to JavaScript so I was taking a YouTube course to try and learn more. When I began making an infinite scrolling background, I got the error 'TypeError: layer.update is not a function' in the console
, this is the scroller code

```js
class Layer {
  constructor(game, width, height, speedModifier, image) {
    this.game = game;
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
    this.height = speedModifier;
    this.image = image;
    this.x = 0;
    this.y = 0;
  }
  update() {
    if (this.x < -this.width) this.x = 0;
    else this.x -= this.game.speed * this.speedModifier;
  }
  draw(context) {
    context.drawImage(this.image, this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
  }
}

export class Background {
  constructor(game) {
    this.game = game;
    this.width = 1667;
    this.height = 500;
    this.layer5image = document.getElementById("layer5");
    this.layer1 = new Layer(
      this.game,
      this.width,
      this.height,
      1,
      this.layer5image
    );
    console.log(this.layer5image);
    this.backgroundLayers = [layer1];
  }
  update() {
    this.backgroundLayers.forEach(function (layer) {
      layer.update();
    });
  }
  draw(context) {
    this.backgroundLayers.forEach((layer) => {
      layer.draw(context);
    });
  }
}

const b = new Background();
b.update();
```

I tried to ask ChatGPT and I thought that that would help, it did not, instead it told me to add arrow syntax, which I already did. After that I looked at microsoft IntelliSense(or whatever it's called) and changed it to an anonymous function(or something like that), I honestly didn't expect anything and nothing happened

Comment: Look at your dev console, it'll have an error in the constructor.

Comment: Don't ask ChatGPT for coding help.  It's not a debugger. It can lead you astray or just be unhelpful or confusing, especially when you are starting out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `Background`'s constructor, you use initialize `this.layer1` as a layer, then use `layer1`, without `this`, making it undefined, therefore, it can not find `update`.

Here is the correct code:

```
constructor(game){
    this.game = game;
    this.width = 1667;
    this.height = 500;
    this.layer5image = document.getElementById('layer5');
    this.layer1 = new Layer(this.game, this.width, this.height, 1, this.layer5image)
    console.log(this.layer5image);
    this.backgroundLayers = [this.layer1]; // `layer1` is a property of `this`
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I made a mistake  when assigning `BackgroundLayer` which caused it to be undefined (you can find more details in MrDiamond's answer)